# How do I hide the 2nd image when the 1st image is clicked and then make it show back again on the second click?

Tags: jquery, html, image, hide, show

So what I'm trying to do with this code is make the second image appear when I click on the 1st image and then disappear upon a second click.

For the example and code see and click on the 1st image: http://jsfiddle.net/dc234561/QLdck/

HTML:

```
<img name="MP" id="mp" img src="img/gorillaz-plasticbeach.jpg" data-artist="Gorillaz" data-album="Plastic Beach"/>
<img id="loadingImage" src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mp").click(function(){
    $("#loadingImage").show();
  });
  $("#mp").click(function(){
    $("#loadingImage").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your HTML is malformed, `img` should only appear *once*, and be the first thing inside of the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of binding the event twice,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mp").click(function () {
        $("#loadingImage").toggle();
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QLdck/1/)